# I want to count city column's values which are repeated

Tags: sql, oracle

```
id city
1  London
2  Rome
3  London
4  Rome
```

Expected output like this:

```
London    Rome
     2       2
```

Using case expression...

How can I solve this query?

Comment: You need to group by 'city' and include `COUNT(city)` in your select clause.

Comment: @ChristophDahlen already tried this but not able to reach expected output can u please suggest another way to solve this

Comment: Show your statement

Comment: Do you really want one column per repeated city, not a row for each? You would have to know the maximum number of cities to include, to perform conditional aggregation (which I guess is why you refer to a case expression) for each one. That doesn't seem useful.

Comment: Wanting the results as multiple columns, rather than multiple rows, is a SQL Anti-Pattern. Quite literally, SQL is intentionally designed to Not give results in that columnar format. Also, why do you need to use CASE expressions? The pattern you need is aggregation, not a scalar function. This seems like an https://xyproblem.info problem to me.

Answer (score 2):

This is a *standard* aggregation + `group by` + `having` problem.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (id, city) as
  2    (select 1, 'London' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'Rome'   from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'London' from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'Rome'   from dual union all
  6     select 5, 'Zagreb' from dual
  7    )
```

Query:

```
  8  select city,
  9         count(*) cnt
 10  from test
 11  group by city
 12  having count(*) > 1;

CITY          CNT
------ ----------
London          2
Rome            2

SQL>
```

What does `case` expression have to do with it?

Comment: You solution leaves out all single occurences of a city (caused by 'having count(*) > 1').

Comment: @ChristophDahlen - I imagine that's intentional as the title refers to "which is repeted", which implies they only want those with more than one?

Comment: Thank You, But just wanted to know can we solve this question using case statement or not?

Comment: @VikasUbale **You** can solve it by executing the statement and provide feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your output using conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(CASE city WHEN 'London' THEN 1 END) AS London,
       COUNT(CASE city WHEN 'Rome'   THEN 1 END) AS Rome
FROM   table_name
WHERE  city IN ('London', 'Rome')
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, city) AS
SELECT 1, 'London' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Rome' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'London' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Rome' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| LONDON | ROME |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |

However, in this case, it is unclear how to handle your requirement for repeated values if the values were not repeated.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MCjHkLyx)

Comment: Thank you finally i got the output as per requirment